# How can i solve AttributeError: module 'dis' has no attribute 'COMPILER_FLAG_NAMES' in anaconda3/envs/untitled/lib/python3.7/inspect.py

Tags: python, inspect

i am trying implement from scipy.spatial import distance as dist library however it gives me   File "/home/afeyzadogan/anaconda3/envs/untitled/lib/python3.7/inspect.py", line 56, in 
    for k, v in dis.COMPILER_FLAG_NAMES.items():
AttributeError: module 'dis' has no attribute 'COMPILER_FLAG_NAMES'
error how can i solve it?

'''
for k, v in dis.COMPILER_FLAG_NAMES.items():
    mod_dict["CO_" + v] = k
'''

Answer (score 1):

We ran across this issue in our code with the same exact AttributeError.
Turns out it was a totally unrelated file in the current directory called `dis.py`.